# Allow privileged users to filter out edited questions on front page, and only show "New" questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, homepage

Sometimes, I would like to look at the front page, and *only* see the newest questions. And I would rather not see questions that were pushed up because of new-answers or edits.

Please consider a privilege that lets users of ... say, 5000 rep , filter out the stream of questions to show only "New".

This is somewhat open-ended/brief at this point, as it's just the possible first step towards a real proposal(just because we don't know if others may be interested).

Comment: Clicking the "Questions" button does just that.

Comment: @jonsca - Thank you, I didn't realize that part. hmm, But what about Something more permanent?

Comment: "Questions" is at the top of every page, I'd say that's just about as permanent as you can get.  No high rep requirement!

Comment: @jonsca - OK then, but what if I wanted to default to that setting? i.e. would you agree it's useful give the option to *always* show new on front page... if I want that?

Comment: Instead of clicking on the logo to back to the front page, just click on "Questions".  If you start from a bookmark just have it set to `meta.stackoverflow.com/questions` instead of the main page.  I think anything else is just overcomplicated for not much gain.

Comment: @jonsca - OK I'm sold, i think you're right it would be an overcomplication. Thank you Sir